# Why don't new registrations show up in members

Tags: freemember

I just can't get the Freemember registration form to work.
I'm using the default form from the docs:

```
    {exp:freemember:register return="login" error_handling="inline" error_delimiters='<span class="error">|</span>'}

    <p>
        <label for="email">Email</label><br />
        {field:email}<br />
        {error:email}
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="password">Password</label><br />
        {field:password}<br />
        {error:password}
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="password_confirm">Confirm Password</label><br />
        {field:password_confirm}<br />
        {error:password_confirm}
    </p>

    <p>
        {field:accept_terms} <label for="accept_terms">Accept Terms</label><br />
        {error:accept_terms}
    </p>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>

{/exp:freemember:register}
```

The form sends but nothing happens. I'm not sure what to even do to get this to set up and work properly. Do I need certain settings I'm missing in member preferences? When I use the default EE member/registration form it works just fine.

EE 2.6.1
Freemember 2.2.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is most likely an error being thrown but not being displayed. A few things to check...

Double check that it's installed correctly and listed in Addons > Modules.

Then ensure that you have [set your encryption key](https://github.com/expressodev/freemember#installation) in `system/expressionengine/config/config.php`.

The next thing to try would be to remove `error_handling="inline"` so you can see any errors that are returned on form submission.

You're also including `accept_terms` in your registration form. In Members > Member Preferences, look for "Require Terms of Service". It could be worth setting this to 'No' to test with. You could even try removing that from your form if you set this 'No'.

Does any of that help to shed any light on things? Are there any errors returned?

Comment: It seems that getting rid of the accept_terms and shutting it off in member prefs did the trick. However, no email is submitted, I have "self-activation via email" set. I also get an "error loading page" from my return url. Looks like i made one step forward, but more hurdles lie ahead still.

Comment: The return URL just needs to be set to an active URL in a template_group/template pattern as usual. If `login` doesn't exist then it will return an error.

Comment: In terms of the email. That could very well be your email settings in Admin > Email Configuration. What protocol are you using?

Comment: I had a misspelled template return path, working now.

Comment: I'm using PHP Mail protocol. I'm also working local with MAMP stack. I figure things should sort themselves out when I'm in a live environment.

Comment: Sounds like it's nearly there. PHP Mail should work fine with MAMP. Ensure that you have the Email module installed (it only comes with the commercial version). [These instructions](http://blog-en.mamp.info/2009/09/how-to-sending-emails-with-mamp-pro.html) should help getting MAMP setup for email.

Comment: I enabled the email module and set up MAMP based on the instructions but still not working. If I run a basic php mail() function outside of EE it works fine. I guess that's for another thread though.

Comment: Probably best to set up sendgrid (free for low volume) to send your mail from your development server, to rule out any delivery issues. Freemember actually doesn't have anything to do with the member registration emails, these are sent automatically by EE when the member is created.

Comment: Andy, you want to mark this as answered, so that the answerer gets his points, right?